# Where is the documentation on writing a blogger template?

Tags: blogger, blogger-themes

I have been playing around with blogger themes and the customizer and noticed that different themes show different customization options. I also see some themes use completely undocumented features.

My question is, where can I find documentation on the blogger template language and ideally how these affect the "customizer"?

I did find the [five articles at Google support](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/176245?hl=en) which does not offer enough information. I also found two questions ([Q1](https://support.google.com/blogger/thread/72224901/where-can-i-find-and-learn-about-developing-my-own-blogger-template?hl=en), [Q2](https://support.google.com/blogger/thread/53711413/blogger-template-and-documentation?hl=en)) on the community page which do not offer much extra help.

As an **example** of topics that I cannot find documentation for (again, my question is if there is any in-depth documentation about blogger templating language, and not with the questions below specifically):

- `<macro:include>`... cannot find any documentations about it or what it does
- The "Awesome" theme allow me to select the "layout" in the customizer, but no idea how that is described in the template itself. E.g., can choose sidebar location, number of sidebars, or number of columns in the footer
- How to define the theme colors that show in the advanced selection? Some themes have tens show, others a handful.
- Some themes allow to "adjust widths", but others do not.
- Documentation about what the supported page elements like sections or widgets are?

Answer (score -1):

You can read below article from Google Blogger Support Forum:

- Layouts Data Tags: https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270?hl=en
- Page elements tags for layouts: https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46888?hl=en&ref_topic=6321969
- Widget tags: https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46995?hl=en&ref_topic=6321969#zippy=%2Cincludes-binclude

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).